# How to negate specific words in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to match the statement which should not contain words other than (AND,and,OR,or). I have written following code for this:

```
Matcher mat2 = Pattern.compile(".*\\bAND|and|OR|or\\b.*").matcher(
            expression);
    boolean b2 = mat2.find();
```

and my input string is like

> (1 not and 2 or ( 3 and 4))

So it is returning result as true. But as the input contains 'not' string output should be false. So I tried so many ways already given on stackoverflow to negate the expression, but not working for me.I tried ^.*(?!AND|and|OR|or).*$ but it is always returning true result.

Comment: Try `.*(AND|and|OR|or).*`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to match a string that has only words from the list, and no other letter in the string.

You may use

```
^(?:[^a-zA-Z]*(?:or|OR|and|AND))+[^a-zA-Z]*$
```

Or case insensitively:

```
(?i)^(?:[^a-z]*(?:or|and))+[^a-z]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LkNW46/1)

With `String#matches()`, the `^` and `$` become redundant:

```
s.matches("(?i)(?:[^a-z]*(?:or|and))+[^a-z]*")
```

**Details**:

- `(?i)` - `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`  embedded option (note that if you need to only match specific case variants like `or`, `OR` and `AND`/`and`, use the alternation as in the first regex example)
- `^` - start of string (optional with `matches()`)
- `(?:[^a-z]*(?:or|and))+` - 1 or more occurrences (so, at least 1 `or` or `and` must be present) of:

  - `[^a-z]*` - 0+ chars other than ASCII letters
  - `(?:or|and)` - either `or` or `and` literal char sequences
- `[^a-z]*`
- `$` - end of string  (optional with `matches()`).

Comment: Assuming the OP doesn't want to match strings like `1and2and3` or `1and2or` I'd make the first and last char class non-optional and add whitespace, e.g. `(?i)^(?:[^a-z]+\s+(?:or|and)\s+)+[^a-z]+$`.

Comment: @Thomas: I understand there are more ways to enhance this, e.g. we may use word boundaries - `s.matches("(?i)(?:[^a-z]*\\b(?:or|and)\\b)+[^a-z]*")`. Actually, it is just one approach, there can be another one: replace all the `and` and `or` words with `.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(?:and|or)\\b", "")` and then check if there is a letter: `.matches("(?s)[^a-z]*[a-z].*")`. If there is a match, the string is no pass.

Comment: Yes word boundaries would help as well. Still I'd use `[^a-z]+` to not match strings that start or end with `and` or  `or` and  try to match the whitespace explicitly in order not to match trailing whitespace (e.g. using word boundaries you'd get a match for `"1 and 2 or"` and `"1 and 2 or "`).